# How to get only the array key with laravel validation message?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have an array which is up for validation. The validation is working perfectly. But I can't return the proper message.

My request array is like

```
mobile = 'tom'=> '0011120', 'dick'=> null, 'harry'=>'001212'
```

As you can see the mobile number of dick is null. It should return an error. `'the mobile number of dick is required.'`

I have tried,

```
$validator = Validator::make(request()->all(),
[
    'mobile.*' => 'required'
],
[
    'mobile.*.required' => 'the mobile number of :key is required.'
];
```

When I return the error is like `'the mobile number of mobile.dick is required.'` How can I remove `mobile.dick` and get only the name portion?

Comment: did you try  'mobile.*.required' =>'the mobile number of :attribute is required.' ?

Comment: Do you want to ignore validation rule for only dick name ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 yes.. Same message is coming

Comment: @BKF.. I don't want to ignore any rules. The rules portion is working perfectly. The message portion is giving problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, since they use a simple `str_replace` on :key and messageKey.

You can override it a little, using your own variable, not amazing code but will work :

```
$validator = Validator::make(request()->all(),
[
    'mobile.*' => 'required'
],
[
    'mobile.*.required' =>'the mobile number of :key is required.'
];

$errors = null;
if ($validator->errors()) {
    $errors = [];
    foreach ($validator->errors()->all() as $error) {
        $errors []= str_replace('mobile.', '', $error);
    }
}

// $errors will contain proprer message, or null if no error
dd($errors);
```

Comment: Yes ! you're right, since I 'm note on my PC to test it, may he replace the whole message.

Comment: It is working. I just added a $errors = new MessageBag($errors); so that it returns a messagebag; not an array.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this :

```
 'mobile.*.required' =>'the mobile number of '.str_replace('mobile.','',:key) .'is required.'
```

Comment: It is giving me error. "syntax error, unexpected ':' ".. str_replace('mobile.','',:key),,, Here :key is probably not acceptable.